# How does the supply of M and L ships work?

Tags: x3-terran-conflict

As you know, there are sometimes M and L ships available at Shipyards. But not always in stock and I could not figure out what determines if they are available or not.

So I would like to ask what the factor is for those better equipped ships to be available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually shipyards are linked to the equipment dock (or sometimes a corporate HQ) within the same sector.  If the linked dock/hq has all the equipment needed to fulfill a M or L order, then you can purchase them.  You can click on the M and L ships to pull up info on what comes as standard for those tiers.

If there are enough supplies, you can purchase multiple M/L ships rather than having to bother with equipping them manually to save time.

Answer (score 2):

Actually, according to this thread on the official X series forums, the availability of M and L class ships is randomized.

http://forum.egosoft.com/viewtopic.php?p=4007856

From the page...

> Availability at a shipyard is randomised every time you change a few
>   sectors or reload. S is always available, M sometimes, and L
>   infrequently. Just keep trying your reloads or sector changes and keep
>   looking in different shipyards (satellites or cheap docked ships are
>   useful for that) until the RNG favours you. No other factors
>   (equipment stock in local Equipment Docks etc) have the slightest
>   effect on it.
>   --Alan Phipps

Comment: Could you summarize key points of the page you link to in the event the site goes down and no one can verify your evidence